# How to pass form data values to controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**C# MVC app with Razor views**

I am trying to submit a form using Jquery and want to know how to override values in "data". When I click on submit and debug the controller action I can see all the data.

On my form I have the name of an artist.

I am trying to override the artist name using javascript before submitting the data.

If thats not possible I would like to just pass the artist name to the controller.

Here is my script to submit the form.

```
var artist = "Dick"

$('#publishingForm').submit(function(){


    $.post('PublishVideo', $('#publishingForm').serialize(), artist, function (data) {
        data.artists = artists;
        //call back happens here. 
    });

    return false; 

});
```

So two questions:

1. How can I  override values in "data"?
2. How can I pass an argument when making the call? I am not sure of the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to update the artist input before making the POST with something like this:

```
var artist = 'Dick';
$('#publishingForm').submit(function(){
    $('#id_for_the_artist_input').val(artist);


    $.post('PublishVideo', $('#publishingForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        data.artists = artists;
        //call back happens here. 
    });

    return false; 

});
```

Or, you can pass an additional URL parameter like this:

```
var artist = 'Dick';
$('#publishingForm').submit(function(){

    var params = $('#publishingForm').serialize();
    params = params + '&artistOverride=' + artist;

    $.post('PublishVideo', params, function (data) {
        data.artists = artists;
        //call back happens here. 
    });

    return false; 

});
```

Comment: I updated my answer based on an edit of the question.  Also fixed a syntax error.

Comment: The first part is not working. For some reason the code at  $('#id_for_the_artist_input').val('Dick'); cannot be reached

Comment: You'll need to post more code for me to help debug more.  It would be useful to see the relevant parts of the Razor / HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of using form submit you could manually create and hydrate a JSON object with whatever values you need and then post that object with the $.ajax or $.post.  For example, something along [these lines](http://jsfiddle.net/D6jqW/):

```
// HTML markup
<input id="artist" type="text" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" />

// JS
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var artistInfo = {
        name: $("#artist").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Artist/Save",
        data: artistInfo,
        success: function (data) {
            // handle success callback
        },
        dataType: function (data) {
            // handle success callback
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```